# fnReloadAjax(url): two requests

Tags: datatables

I'd like to refresh my table when new item is added. I use such code:

```
$("#frm_create_user").submit(function() {

    var formData = getFormData($("#frm_create_user"));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: getApiUrl("/user"),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({user:{user_ref: formData.user_ref}}),
    }).done(function(r) {

        oTable.fnReloadAjax(getApiUrl("/users?sSearch=" + r.user.userid));

    });

    return false;

});
```

But for some reason, I can see two requests instead of one.
The first one is correct - `http://symfony/app_dev.php/api/users?sSearch=kZoh1s23&_=1394204041433`

And the second one is confusing - `http://symfony/app_dev.php/api/users?sSearch=kZoh1s23&sEcho=3&iColumns=8&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=25&mDataProp_0=userid&mDataProp_1=user_ref&mDataProp_2=password&mDataProp_3=vpn_password&mDataProp_4=status_id&mDataProp_5=expire_account&mDataProp_6=created&mDataProp_7=&sSearch=&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=false&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=true&bSortable_6=true&bSortable_7=true&_=1394204041505`

If I remove fnReloadAjax() line, these two requests gone so that it looks like it is caused by `fnReloadAjax()`

How may I fix it to have only `http://symfony/app_dev.php/api/users?sSearch=kZoh1s23&_=1394204041433` requests?

Answer (score 0):

All these confusing parameters are Informations that your server sided script might need to clamp the data that has to be returned to dataTables.
Since I don't know your server sided code, I can only break up what they are good for:

```
&sEcho=3  //No need to react to this, it's just the result of the last ajax call
&iColumns=8 //Your table has 8 columns
&iDisplayStart=0 //You are on page 1
&iDisplayLength=25 //you want to display up to 25 entrys per page
&mDataProp_0=userid //Your first colum gets the value of [userid]
&mDataProp_1=user_ref //Your first colum gets the value of [user_ref]
&mDataProp_2=password //Your first colum gets the value of [password]
etc...
&sSearch=12345&bRegex=true//Your first column is filtered by userid 12345 and this value should be treated as a regex by your datasource
&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false//Your second column is not filtered and should not be treated as a regex by your datasource
etc...

&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc //your first column should be sorted ascending
&iSortingCols=1 //you have one column that is sortable
&bSortable_0=true //Column 0 is sortable
&bSortable_1=false //Column 1 is not sortable
etc..
```

Your server sided script should react to these values. In case of a mysql datasource it should set up its where clause to the filtering parameters, limit it by pagenumber and items per page, and sort according to the sortinfo.

All this is needed if you want to use the luxury features of datatables like pagination, sorting, individual column filtering, clamping ajax return values to minify serverload when working with thousands of entrys.

If you don't need that, just ignore the additional parameters in your server script and just react to the data you need. But leave them in, you might need them later:-)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, but my question is different. I got pagination and data filtering configured. The issue is this - I got 2 requests instead of 1. Look at the long query string - `sSearch` is parameter is overwritten because it is appended by the plug-in. So the item is not fetched from the Server.

Comment: So why don't you name your parameter mysSearch and react on the serverside if its set and sSearch is empty?

Comment: Because it is a hack. The goal is to avoid the second request.

Comment: Hmm, you want to have only the new User displayed in your Table? Then make a normal request, clear your table and use fnAddData to make it use only this line. I like hacks:-)

Comment: I tried something similar, but had troubles clearing it. `oTable.fnClearTable()` does nothing for some reason. `fnAddData` does not add new rows either.

Comment: I have found better solution - `fnFilter()`